# How to configure facebook app for subdomain?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-invite

I have created an facebook app, that is working fine. i have also used invite feature of facebook. Invitations are sending successfully, but when i click on the invitation in facebook, it redirects to my app. and shows the below error:

Please help me how can i make this working for sub-domain.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have found that.. i was entering the wrong canvas url.. which redirect to this "www." website.. i have changed that url to without "www".. it resolved my problem..